# Run exec before docker::run block when changed

Tags: puppet

I have the following exec block in my puppet code, which logs me in into an AWS ECR Repo.

```
  exec { 'aws ecr get-login':
    command => "aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1 > /tmp/docker-login.sh;
                 chmod a+x /tmp/docker-login.sh;
                 /tmp/docker-login.sh > /tmp/docker.login",
    path    => ['/bin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', ],
  }
```

As it is now, it gets executed every puppet run, which is a bit of an overkill. I would like to only execute it, when the following block has changes.

```
docker::run { 'test':
    ensure               => present,
    image                => "image:${docker_tag}",
    pull_on_start        => true,
  }
```

I know I can work with notify, the thing is that, when the docker block changes, I would like to run the exec **before** the docker::run statement is processed

Comment: What triggers the docker::run?

Comment: Any changes that happen in the docker::run block